# how to properly get every line containing a specific word in java

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a program that reads a file and checks every line that contains a specific word then prints it.if there isn't one it should print "no match for your search".this is what I've got so far and and I'm having trouble putting it all together.after all my twinkering around and replacing the`while` with `if`or putting the second if statement outside of the while, sometimes it doesn't matter what i enter it always says "no match for your search" and sometimes it says  java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found. and sometimes it freezes and i searched this up and it says its a bug in cmd or something.any help will be appreciated
and I'm new to java so please any thing you can advise me will be helpful and appreciated

```
System.out.println("search for book");
 
String search = scan.next();    
scan.nextLine();    

File file = new File("library.txt");
Scanner in = null;
in = new Scanner(file);
          
String line = in.nextLine();
while(in.hasNext()) {
    if(line.contains(search)) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }   
           
    if(!line.contains(search)) {
        System.out.println("no match for your search");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `String line=in.nextLine();` should be inside the `while` loop.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp yeah originally it was but I was trying to find a solution and...yeah but thank you, I  would have prolly forgot and spent 2 more days figuring it out

Comment: @Johnny Mopp but wont that give a "cannot find symbol "on String line??

Comment: You could use a  a `boolean found = false` that gets set (`found = true;)`when the word is found. Then change the last part to `if (!found) {System.out.println("no match for your search");}`

Comment: @Johnny Mopp thank youuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you seem to skip your first line. Secondly, second if clause is redundant.

```
Boolean found=false;
while(in.hasNext()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    if(line.contains(search)) {
        System.out.println(line);
        found=true;
    }           
}

if(found==false) System.out.println("no match for your search");
```

Answer (score 2):

Not mentioning logical errors in your code, you should probably create logical (boolean) variable outside of the loop and set it to `false`. If you encounter your condition, set it to `true`.
After the while loop, check the value. If it's false, that means no lines were found and you should print your message.

Example:

```
boolean foundAnything = false;
while(...) {
    ...
    if(condition) {
        foundAnything = true;
        ...
    }
    ...
}

// Nothing was found
if(!foundAnything) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> sometimes it doesn't matter what i enter it always says "no match for your search"

The biggest issue here is this part inside your loop:

```
while(in.hasNext()) {
    if(line.contains(search)) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }   
           
    if(!line.contains(search)) {
        System.out.println("no match for your search");
        //HERE!!!
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

`System.exit(0)` will stop the program and nothing else will be executed. So if the `search` word is not found in the line, the program finishes.

> sometimes it says java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

You read the first line before the loop and maybe you have an empty file.

```
File file = new File("library.txt");
Scanner in = null;
in = new Scanner(file);

//this reads the first line of the file
String line = in.nextLine();
while(//rest of code...
```

You can overcome these two issues by:

- Read the contents of the file only in the loop
- Use a flag to check if the word was found
- Stop the loop only if the word was found OR if the file has no more lines
- In the loop, if the word is not found yet, just let it continue
- Avoid using `System#exit` unless really needed
- If after the loop the word was not found, print a message

With these suggestions in mind, your code can be designed like this:

```
File file = new File("library.txt");
Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

//Use a flag to check if the word was found 
boolean found = false;

//Stop the loop only if the word was found OR if the file has no more lines
while (!found && in.hasNextLine()) {
    //Read the contents of the file only in the loop
    String line = in.nextLine();
    if (line.contains(search)) {
        found = true;
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    //In the loop, if the word is not found yet, just let it continue
}
//If after the loop the word was not found, print a message
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("no match for your search");
}
```

Comment: but why does it only read the first line all of a sudden

Comment: What do you mean? Does the code at the bottom behave like that?

Comment: no I uh was talking about this one.the one at the bottom works but whats causing this one to work differently?

Comment: Well, in the code you shared you're opening the Scanner and then immediately reading the first line. I explained this in the part _"You read the first line before the loop and maybe you have an empty file"_